# How will I display images that are not in the apache data directory?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, file-permissions

I am using Zend Framework, and am creating a image upload for users. So, I decided to split the users images by having a folder per user in an example directory such as `/var/www/upload/user` and I am planning to use PHP `mkdir` to create a directory for each user.  While the apache public data directory is at: `/var/www/domain.com/public_html`. So, I am not sure how am I supposed to proceed. Because the images are not in the `public_html` file, how will I link the images and display it on the website? What is the solution to this? or is my setup flawed?

Comment: why save the images outside of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the images outside the public folder, then you probably need to create an controller/action that accepts info that identifies the image and then sends it back to the browser - complete with correct mime headers - via `readfile()`.

In some circumstances, this makes sense: if these resources need to be restricted based upon some Auth/Acl criteria, for example. If the images uploaded by user X are not public to all users/visitors, but private to user X (or some other set of users/visitors you identify), then this approach applies.

But if these image resources are public to all, then running access to them through the entire MVC dispatch cycle seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish what you're saying - Different set of users/visitors may or may not see it. Is there a name for this technique? Any tutorials/references/advice you can share with me for accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a solution like this:

structure your applications:

```
application
data
library
public
```

in application.ini

```
data_uploads = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/uploads"
```

in Bootstrap.php

```
public function _initDefines()
{
    define('DATA_UPLOADS', $this->getOption('data_uploads'));
}
```

for single user create a dir in `data/uploads`

simple and effective! ;)